# Compare two dataframe in Pandas where Column Names are not present

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe:

**df1**

```
   Name Emp ID  Total Salary     A      B     C     D     E
0  Mike   A001         25000  5000  15000  3000  4500  2000
```

**df2(Here column names cannot be assigned )**

```
[5000, 15000, 3000, 2000]
```

How can I compare both data frame and print the matching rows as below:

**Result:**

```
A - 5000    B - 15000    C - 3000    E - 2000
```

Comment: `Here column names cannot be assigned` : Why?

Comment: Because the values of df2 is from a numpy array. And the array values are filled from a function, hence I dont know what values are going to come.

Answer (score 0):

use the numpy array on `df2`

```
df1[['A', 'B', 'C', 'E']] == df2.values

      A     B     C     E
0  True  True  True  True
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
df2.columns=['A','B','C','E']
df1[(df1[df2.columns]==df2.values).columns]
```